# TIBCO Jaspersoft Server empty errorlist

Tags: jasperserver

We are running a TIBCO Jaspersoft Server where JasperReports is installed.

We have developed some small Reports which are running productive.
But now I wanted to add another email recipient in one report and after clicking on save I get an empty errorlist.[enter empty error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Ouj.png)

Attached a screenshot. Has anyone any idea what I can do now? I can't modifiy anything in the setting for any of our reports.

Comment: Did you enable logging? Did you find something interesting at log file(s)?

Comment: After a complete restart the error was gone. Don't know the exact problem.